# Where can i find a good time picker android ui component

Tags: android, components, timepicker

I'm looking for a better time-picker component (Better that the default one), does someone can tell me where i can find one (even better if it's for free) ?

Thanks,
Lior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wheel date and time picker is useful in every situation when the user has to set the time or date. it provides a more fun way of setting date and time than the standard plus-minus way. If you want your users to be able to set the time using the keyboard, consider using the plus minus date and time picker.

Follow Two Link:

`Android-wheel`: http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/

`Demo`: http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/downloads/list

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by better. If you are looking for something with a more polished UI you can always try this: http://android-devblog.blogspot.com/2010/05/wheel-ui-contol.html

Answer (score 0):

you can find clock picker at this link:
[ColorPicker](https://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/)
bootstrap3 clock picker Not coordinating with internet explorer